# Activate spell checking in Excel - Office for Mac 2011

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, spell-check, office-for-mac

How can I activate spell checking in Excel in Office for Mac 2011? I would like to have spell checking just the way it is in Word or system wide in OS X.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot. Office:mac does not use the system wide OS X spelling service. Instead it uses [its own set of proofing tools](http://mac2.microsoft.com/help/office/14/en-us/excel/item/6474a4a6-9d3e-4bde-a255-fb9286ef5d10), like the Windows version does. This gives you “as you type” spell checking in Word because Microsoft supports it there, but as to Excel, [Microsoft states](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/choose-how-spell-check-and-grammar-check-work-HP010354280.aspx?CTT=3#_Toc260387887):

> In Microsoft Office Access, Microsoft Office Excel, and Microsoft Office Project, these options are not available. The spelling checker does not work in the background in these programs.